# Why is the query time of my PostgreSQL DB (Postgis) so much slower than in my MySQL DB?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, query-optimization, postgis

I've been testing the performance of my PGSQL DB and MySQL DB with around a million entries and I've come to the conclusion that MySQL seems to execute my queries much faster, but I feel it should be the other way around and that I'm missing something.

I was also trying the query with and without Postgis functions (for example ST_DistanceSphere), and the queries with Postgis functions were slower, which also suprises me since I'd assume that Postgis would be faster.

The queries I'm trying to optimize are for finding the distance between two points using longitude and latitude.

I've created an index for the geom (geometry) column in PGSQL because i thought that might improve the performance, but it still only performs sequential scans, even if the query returns only around 5-10% of the database entries.

Both DBs have the same data inside of them.
Below I've attached images of the queries and their time to execute and an explain analyze.

[Query 1 PGSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVvy3.png) (Fastest, without using Postgis Functions)

```
WITH users_filtered AS (
SELECT id, pseudonym, city, (6371 * acos( 
                cos( radians(users.latitude) ) 
              * cos( radians( 49.5099 ) ) 
              * cos( radians( 6.74549 ) - radians(users.longitude) ) 
              + sin( radians(users.latitude) ) 
              * sin( radians( 49.5099 ) )
        ) ) as distance_in_km
FROM users
)
SELECT * FROM users_filtered;

"Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..124501.90 rows=1029033 width=29) (actual time=0.032..932.905 rows=1030000 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=80768"
"Planning:"
"  Buffers: shared hit=361"
"Planning Time: 1.697 ms"
"Execution Time: 984.460 ms"
```

[Query 2 PGSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5s5c.png) (Slowest, with Postgis functions)

```
WITH users_filtered AS (
SELECT id, pseudonym, city, ST_DistanceSphere(
    CAST(point(49.5099, 6.74549) AS geometry),
    users.geom
) AS distance_in_m
FROM users
)
SELECT * FROM users_filtered;

"Gather  (cost=1000.00..10909130.85 rows=1029033 width=29) (actual time=3.739..2583.961 rows=1030000 loops=1)"
"  Workers Planned: 2"
"  Workers Launched: 2"
"  Buffers: shared hit=81778"
"  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..10805227.55 rows=428764 width=29) (actual time=2.096..2147.072 rows=343333 loops=3)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=81778"
"Planning:"
"  Buffers: shared hit=19"
"Planning Time: 0.577 ms"
"Execution Time: 2696.416 ms"
```

[Query 3 PGSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXrWX.png) (Middle, with Postgis functions)

```
WITH users_filtered AS (
    SELECT id, pseudonym, city, ST_DistanceSphere(
        CAST(point(49.5099, 6.74549) AS geometry),
        users.geom
    ) AS distance_in_m
    FROM users
    WHERE ST_DWithin(users.geom, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(49.5099, 6.7454),4326), 200000)
)
SELECT * FROM users_filtered;

"Gather  (cost=1000.00..10806234.80 rows=103 width=29) (actual time=1.526..2071.394 rows=1030000 loops=1)"
"  Workers Planned: 2"
"  Workers Launched: 2"
"  Buffers: shared hit=81674"
"  ->  Parallel Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..10805224.50 rows=43 width=29) (actual time=1.336..1752.659 rows=343333 loops=3)"
"        Filter: st_dwithin(geom, '0101000020E61000007E1D386744C14840ECC039234AFB1A40'::geometry, '200000'::double precision)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=81674"
"Planning:"
"  Buffers: shared hit=23"
"Planning Time: 1.169 ms"
"Execution Time: 2161.133 ms"
```

[Query 1 MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzrM1.png) (Fastest, this exact same query takes 4-5s in PGSQL)

```
SELECT id, pseudonym, city, ROUND(111.045 *
          degrees(acos(cos(radians(49.5099)) *
          cos(radians(users.latitude)) *
          cos(radians(6.74549) -
          radians(users.longitude)) +
          sin(radians(49.5099)) *
          sin(radians(users.latitude)
          )
        )
      )
    ) AS distance_in_km FROM users;

'-> Table scan on users  (cost=272574.70 rows=2515667) (actual time=0.121..1023.582 rows=1030000 loops=1)\n'
```

[Query 2 MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoJxk.png) (Slowest, using [ST_Distance_Sphere](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-convenience-functions.html#function_st-distance-sphere))

```
SELECT id, pseudonym, city, ST_Distance_Sphere(
    point(49.5099, 6.74549),
    point(users.latitude, users.longitude)
) AS distance_in_m FROM users;

'-> Table scan on users (cost=272574.70 rows=2515667) (actual time=0.096..1073.000 rows=1030000 loops=1)\n'
```

[Query 3 MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p29p5.png) (Middle)

```
SELECT id, pseudonym, city, (6371 * acos( 
                cos( radians(users.latitude) ) 
              * cos( radians( 49.5099 ) ) 
              * cos( radians( 6.74549 ) 
              - radians(users.longitude) ) 
              + sin( radians(users.latitude) ) 
              * sin( radians( 49.5099 ) )
        ) ) as distance_in_km
FROM users ORDER BY distance_in_km ASC;

'-> Sort: (6371 * acos((((cos(radians(users.latitude)) * cos(radians(49.5099))) * cos((radians(6.74549) - radians(users.longitude)))) + (sin(radians(users.latitude)) * sin(radians(49.5099))))))  (cost=272574.70 rows=2515667) (actual time=2142.974..2268.429 rows=1030000 loops=1)\n    -> Table scan on users  (cost=272574.70 rows=2515667) (actual time=0.141..1003.752 rows=1030000 loops=1)\n'
```

Does anyone know why PGSQL seems to be so much slower than MySQL, and even more so with the usage of Postgis functions?
I'd appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Please add the table structure (including indexes!) and the entire query plan. Also, post SQL statements as text, not images.. otherwise we cannot copy&paste data to reproduce your environment. Cheers

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add the [execution plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html) generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers, format text)`** (_not_ just a "simple" explain) of the slow query as  [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you preserve the indention of the plan. Paste the text, then put `\`\`\`` on the line before the plan and on a line after the plan.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, i didn't want the question to get too long so i've just used images, now i've added all of the code blocks, is anything still missing?

Comment: @RomanJ I can't tell why mysql is faster in your case (I never used it with spatial data) but computing distance over a sphere is known to be [much slower](https://dbfiddle.uk/j6VMr0hN) than on a plane surface. I hope some mysql expert answer your question :) +1 for the edit btw.

Comment: @RomanJ - EXPLAINs (or equivalent)

Comment: @JimJones - ST_...() are builtin functions, hence _much_ faster than that lengthy expression.  (I've compared them in MySQL).

Comment: One query has a WHERE clause. Another has an ORDER BY clause. The rest simply retrieve all the rows of your table while computing the great circle distance. It doesn't make much sense to compare the performance of such different queries, with such different execution plans. Please consider [edit]ing your question to explain your problem in more detail.